# How to show an background image until the image loads

Tags: javascript, html

If I create a photo gallery page in an image then for slow connections the images do not load so fast.

How can I create such page in which an image loads first which will be applied to all the backgrounds of the images until it loads and cover the light image that is loaded earlier.

Comment: This feels off-topic (too broad) since it could be done with pure css or in many ways in javascript. However, for the pure-css solution, check multiple-backgrounds: https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/ (the first one would be a common image for all of them).

Comment: I think he have HTML images tag and he want them to have a background (gif for example) until the image load. the SRC tag will act like stacking background but it's schementically better to put the real image if they are relative to the content (like a gallery or etc). Having a div with css background have the side-effect that screen reader won't read it (bad for accessibility) and crawler will ignore them or consider them as decoration only. It's better to have the real img in your HTML and apply it a background (that is a decoration until the image load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply a background to your image. If they are all JPG (with no trasparency), you could do this:

CSS

```
   img{
      background: url(path/to/my/file.jpg) center center no-repeat;
   }
```

Note that if you have trasparency, your image will appear over the background and it will not be beautiful. Else, it should work like a charm this way.